# PHP and javascript combining variables issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I have a PHP file where I display a html table (HTML) with data from a mysql table.

```
<?php
include 'connexion.php';
session_start();
$idfirm = $_REQUEST['idfirm'];
$namefirm = $_REQUEST['namefirm'];
```

The rows in the table have the

```
<tr class="clickableRow"...
```

Then on row click (javascript) I want to be able to call (POST) another PHP file that will display other information based on some info from the table row.
I have difficulties in achieving this.

What I have done so far is:

```
echo '
...
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
          $(".clickableRow").click(function() {
                var tableData = $(this).children("td").map(function() {
                    return $(this).text();
                }).get();

// So I can access the field data either like this
                var myID = $.trim(tableData[0]); 
// or like this:
                var name = $(this).closest(\'tr\').find(\'td:eq(1)\').text();
                alert(myID);';
echo"  // here I would need to access some variables that I received above in PHP from POST
                    var namefirmx = '{$namefirm}';
                    var idfirmx = '{$idfirm}';
";
// and here I would like to call another PHP file (with POST) that will display info about the employee
```

So, how can I make a POST to another php file and send POST variables:name,namefirmx, idfirmx,myID

**I am not sure how to make the POST.**

I believe there is no other way to call the POST but javascript. (Remember that the POST must be made on row click)

Please help me out here...

Comment: A simple way - create a form with hidden elements and method attribute "post" in each row, and when user clicked on row, send submit event to form in javascript. But need ajax?

Comment: I don't need Ajax. I do not need anything to be returned from the final PHP file. I need the final PHP to be displayed (since it contains HTML and shows stuff, including Buttons that will help in further navigation)

Comment: How do I create forms on each row? Seems like I would make this very heavy like this. Since I can access the onclick event, and also I can access the variables that I need for the POST... is there no way to call the POST straight from this function (rowclick)? I imagined the POST just bellow my above code... in a few lines, just like any other js function. Was I wrong?

Comment: You can use a single form on the page, but at final you need to post a data via form.

Answer (score 1):

You can always add php variables inside your js code like the following :

```
<?php 
$x="ABC";
?>
<script language="javascript">
jsX="<?php echo $x;?>";
alert(jsX);
</script>
```

Comment: I edited my question because in the meantime I solved the "getting" the php vars like echo "var namefirmx = '{$namefirm}';"; Thank you anyway, I will +1 your answer though. Please help me achieve the POST

Comment: I tried this already, but the POST does not happen. This is my code: $.post( "modiemployee.php", { idfirm: idfirmx, namefirm: namefirmx, idx: myID } ); Nothing happens, just the alerts show up. I need the modiemployee.php to be displayed just like when POST-ing from a simple HTML form in a simple HTML/PHP page

Answer (score 1):

Quick example of php script, some html tags are missed, but I think you will get a picture:

```
<?php 
print_r($_POST);
?>

<script src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
          $(".clickableRow").click(function() {
            $(this).find("form").submit();
          });
    });            
</script>

<table border="1">
  <tr class="clickableRow">
     <td>
          <form method="post"><input type="hidden" name="p1" value="v1"><input type="hidden" name="p2" value="v2"></form>
          v1
     </td>
     <td>v2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Seems like it would make my code extremely difficult to read and prone to errors. Thank you for the answer. I will +1 it since it's a valid answer. The answer I posted (in the same time) uses a more simplified code, that is composed of one JS function that I can call without changing the HTML. However, if nobody else considers that your answer is bad..., then I will accept your answer since it seems a good one (I did not try it)

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem using a SO previous question. I am not sure what to do with this question.
Anyway, the answer is: adding a function in javascript, and calling it with my variables.
The function is:

```
        function post_to_url(path, params, method) {
            method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.

            // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
            // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
            var form = document.createElement("form");
            form.setAttribute("method", method);
            form.setAttribute("action", path);

            for(var key in params) {
                if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
                    hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                    hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
                    hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

                    form.appendChild(hiddenField);
                 }
            }
            document.body.appendChild(form);
            form.submit();
        }
```